# Получить связи Laravel

Tags: laravel

```
public function show(Branch $branch)
{

    return new BranchResource($branch->load(['products']));
}
```

Все работает, у продуктов тоже есть связи оплат, как мне еще получить и передать сразу связи у продуктов? 
Типа такой записи

```
return new BranchResource($branch->load(['products']->load(products->pay));
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашел правильное решение, нужно использовать точечную нотацию.

```
return new BranchResource($branch->load(['products.pays']));
```